# Convert c++ char array to c# string

Tags: c#, c++, c, arrays, string

I have a struct in C++ which has a char[10] field.

```
struct Package
{
    char str[10];
};
```

I convert the struct into char array and send it to and c# application over a TCP socket and there I convert it back to a c# struct.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Package
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 10)]
    public string str;
};
```

The convertion is done properly and I get the message but the problem is when the length of the message is less than the size of the array and I think that it's due to the null terminator in c++ char array.

For instance if the I send "Hello\0" from C++ the char array is something like:

H e l l o \0 \0 \0 \0 \0

And when I get it in c# application it is something like:

H e l l o Ì Ì Ì Ì Ì

And I really don't know what to do with this (personally like to call) junk character 'Ì'.

please help me on this. Any help is appreciated.

**Update:**

I simply cast the struct to char* and send it over the socket;

```
Package pkg;
strcpy_s(pkg.str, 'Hello\0');

char* bytes = (char*)&pkg;

send(socket, bytes, sizeof(pkg), NULL);
```

Comment: Your array size is 10. Try type 10 characters. You don't have this   character 'Ì'.So you can split string. This is one solution.

Comment: Your solution is good for 10 character but what if I need to have more and more characters. Howerver your answer reminded me of that I can have an end of the string character when I send the char array from c++. Still I'm waiting for more helps.

Comment: It seems that in c# code you doesn't receive '\0' char. Or is never sent to you in C++, but in c++ the array is set "memsetted" to 0x00 for all chars by default

Comment: Actually even if I put '\0' at the end of the char array in C++ it never receives in c#.

Comment: I thnk we need more code. Paste the way you use to pass from C++ array to C# string

Comment: Here is a little problem with recognize. You can have dynamic char array, and you split word,_H e l l o \0 \0 \0 \0 \0_ is now _H e l l o_ and you don't have this problem.

Comment: Can you show the code that converts it to a char array and sends it to the socket?

Comment: I updagted the question.

Comment: what is this `strcpy_s(pkg.str, 'Hello\0');`?

Comment: Is strcpy with security checks. Improvements in apis

Comment: I can't simple assign "Hello\0" to pkg.str by the code pkg.str = "Hello\0" since it is not a pointer and I use strcpy_s;

Comment: No no no, I mean `'Hello\0'` is that some C# thing? or is it C++, if it's the second, then, did you copy it erroneously to SO, or does it compile this way? I don't think you can compile it this way for several reasons.

Comment: @iharob I don't have that technical information. I just did it in a way I thought it fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know any C#, but may be you can solve the problem this way

```
Package pkg;
strcpy_s(pkg.str, 10, "Hello");

char* bytes = (char*)&pkg;

send(socket, bytes, sizeof(pkg), NULL);
```

The `strcpy_s` function takes the size of the `dst` buffer as an argument to avoid an overflow (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td1esda9.aspx)). I asked in the comments about the way you inovke it, because it doesn't even look like it's valid C++.

The terminating null byte is added to `pkg.str` automatically and also `"Hello"` has a terminating null byte after the `o` character, and you don't have to add it manually.

I assumed that C# knows how to handle the recieved string, so if you send the right string, it should be recived correctly.

Comment: It amazingly worked. I don't know why you received a negative vote. Anyway what is the explanation?

Comment: BTW: `sizeof(pkg)` is perfectly ok as long as `pkg.str` is an array and not a pointer, if it is a pointer, then it would be `sizeof(pkg) + strlen(pkg.str) + 1`, the `+ 1` for the terminating null byte. And you wold have to allocate space for the string using `malloc`.

Answer (score 2):

You are sending sizeof array instead of strlen of str.

Take notes that if you send with strlen you need to add 1 to send the null termination of string

Answer (score 1):

This is what I usually do in my wrappers dll with serial line

```
        public byte[] RXArray = new byte[length];

        byte[] appo = new byte[MsgLength];
        Array.ConstrainedCopy(RXArray, NcharsToCopy, appo, 0, MsgLength);
        string ConvertedToString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(appo);
```